# Question on one step in proof of prime factorization

Tags: number-theory

This is from https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/higher_math_online/section03.05.html.

The question is how could this $[p_1 p_2 \dots p_j] = [p^{j-i} q_1 q_2 \dots q_k]$ equal $[0]$?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume $[a]=[b]$ means $a\equiv b\pmod p$. In that case $[p^{i-j}q_1\cdots q_k]=[0]$ since $p$ is a factor of $p^{i-j}q_1\cdots q_k$.